# How to replace particular text string with other string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace string: `6/9/1985 1234567890 ABC test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS`

to convert this in:

`6/9/1985 1234567890 abc_test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS`

Actually I want to replace whitespace between email and string just before email with underscore, string to lowercase.

Comment: Show us what you have tried before.

Comment: You could try a look-ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when you need to modify a string with `replace`, you can pass captured substrings of text to a callback function where you ca maniplate them further.

So, you need a regex that captures the word before an email:

```
(\S+)\s+([^@\s]+@\S+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW5pQ3/1) and a sample code below:

```js
var s = '6/9/1985 1234567890 ABC test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS';
var res = s.replace(/(\S+)\s+([^@\s]+@\S+)/, function (m, grp1, grp2, offset, input) {
  return grp1.toLowerCase() + "_" + grp2;
 });
document.write(res);
```

Comment: Hi, actually that issue is got solved but I have a new one now,

6/9/1985 1234567890 XYZ ABC test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS

6/9/1985 1234567890 xyz_abc_test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS

So, what i want now if there is any alphanumeric char between number (e.g. 1234567890) and email (e.g. test@yahoo.co.in) those I need to replace with lowercase char while white-space will replace with underscore.

Help me out here.

Comment: If it is related to this issue you have, please let me know. If not, post a new question.

Comment: I created a new one here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334910/replace-all-word-between-number-and-email-address-in-lowercase-separating-each-o