# Replace all word between number and email address in lowercase separating each other with underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

```
6/9/1985 1234567890 XYZ ABC test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS
```

Want to convert this in:

```
6/9/1985 1234567890 xyz_abc_test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS
```

So, what i want is if there is any alphanumeric chars between number (e.g. `1234567890`) and email (e.g. `test@yahoo.co.in`) those I need to replace with lowercase chars while white-space will replace with underscore.

Comment: `_` is a valid character in email addresses, you will not be able to transform back after this operation

Comment: Actually, I am reading text from pdf but that reader is not recogizing underscore and converting that into white-space. So, i need to fix that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a callback:

```
var t = '6/9/1985 1234567890 XYZ ABC test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS';

var r = t.replace (
    /((?:^|\s)\d+\s+)((?:[a-z]\w*\b\s+)*)(?=[^\s@]+@)/gim, 
    function($0, $1, $2) {
        return $1 + $2.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "_");
    }
);

//=> "6/9/1985 1234567890 xyz_abc_test@yahoo.co.in 301 DURGA NIWAS"
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wx3u39gt/6/)

Comment: If string is e.g. 

9849358253\n9290149055 abc@yahoo.co.in

then it is not able to ignore number giving me

9849358253 9290149055_abc@yahoo.co.in

Comment: Actually I am using some pdf reader for reading pdf text which is adding new line if any enter encounter in pdf

Comment: '9849358253\n9290149055 abc@yahoo.co.in' or '9849358253 9290149055 abc@yahoo.co.in' anyone will work for me

Comment: Create a JSFiddle test with your input as above code is already giving `'9849358253\n9290149055 abc@yahoo.co.in'`

Comment: Check my updated answer with enhanced regex and updated JSFiddle demo.